He loses his sense of touch while trying to have sex
The man sometimes loses some of his 5 senses or sometimes some of them gets a bit boosted and is incapable of getting his penis erected.
Some of the scenes i know. like his sense of sight gets boosted and he could focus on a girl's breasts from his room window. I don't remember the movie's name. 

Please try to give as much detail as possible - like when did you see this movie, any idea how old it might be, was it a drama or a comedy, or some other genre.

My first thought was Senseless from 1998 starring Marlon Wayans. 
The Marlon Wayans character takes an experimental drug that is meant to enhance his 5 senses, but after taking an extra dose, he finds that only 4 of his senses will work at a time.
I found a clip on YouTube which may be the scene you're thinking of.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLrM7OaMTGg

Vaguely reminiscent of 2011 Perfect Sense with Ewan McGregor and Eva Green.  A chef loses his sense of taste, then other senses one by one, due to  global pandemic.
